# Converting a list into comma-separated string with "and" before the last item - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created this function to parse the list:

```
listy = ['item1', 'item2','item3','item4','item5', 'item6']


def coma(abc):
    for i in abc[0:-1]:
        print i+',',
    print "and " + abc[-1] + '.'

coma(listy)

#item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, and item6.
```

Is there a neater way to achieve this?
This should be applicable to lists with any length.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When there are 1+ items in the list (if not, just use the first element):

```
>>> "{} and {}".format(", ".join(listy[:-1]),  listy[-1])
'item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 and item6'
```

Edit: If you need an *Oxford comma* (didn't know it even existed!) -- just use: `", and"` instead:

```
>>> "{}, and {}".format(", ".join(listy[:-1]),  listy[-1])
'item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, and item6'
```

Comment: **Note**: the OP's example uses the [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

Comment: This solution works only with lists, don't handle the case of empty or one-element lists, and uses `+` to concatenate strings, which is discouraged, and should be replaced with `.format`.

Comment: @Daniel:  don't disagree at all. The focus of my answer was purely on `join(..)` and slicing. OP should be able to handle empty lists, one item lists (as I have called out in my answer), and `.format(..)` on his own.

Answer (score 7):

```
def oxford_comma_join(l):
    if not l:
        return ""
    elif len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    else:
        return ', '.join(l[:-1]) + ", and " + l[-1]

print(oxford_comma_join(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']))
```

**Output:**

```
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, and item6
```

Also as an aside the Pythonic way to write

```
for i in abc[0:-1]:
```

is

```
for i in abc[:-1]:
```

Comment: This shouldn't have a downvote. It's clear and is the only answer that actually meets the requirements of the OP. +1

Answer (score 4):

```
def coma(lst):
    return '{} and {}'.format(', '.join(lst[:-1]), lst[-1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Correction for Craig’s answer above for a 2-element list (I’m not allowed to comment):

```
def oxford_comma_join(l):
    if not l:
        return ""
    elif len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    elif len(l) == 2:
        return l[0] + " and " + l[1]
    else:
        return ', '.join(l[:-1]) + ", and " + l[-1]

print(oxford_comma_join(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']))

print(oxford_comma_join(['i1', 'i2']))
```

Results:

```
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, and item6
i1 and i2
```

Answer (score 2):

One more different way to do:

```
listy = ['item1', 'item2','item3','item4','item5', 'item6']
```

**first way**:

```
print(', '.join('and, ' + listy[item] if item == len(listy)-1 else listy[item]
for item in xrange(len(listy))))

output >>> item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, and, item6
```

**second way**:

```
print(', '.join(item for item in listy[:-1]), 'and', listy[-1])

output >>> (item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, 'and', 'item6')
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot take full credit but if you want succinct -- I modified [RoadieRich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982008/1508101) to use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and also made it more concise. It uses the solution by [RootTwo given in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981302/converting-a-list-into-comma-separated-string-with-and-before-the-last-item/38982008#comment65484272_38982008) on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982008/1508101):

```py
def join(items):
    *start, last = items
    return f"{','.join(start)}, and {last}" if start else last
```

Comment: if not items:
    return ""

Answer (score 1):

In python, many functions, that work with lists also works with iterators (like `join`, `sum`, `list`). To get the last item of a iterable is not that easy, because you cannot get the length, because it may be unknown in advance.

```
def coma_iter(iterable):
    sep = ''
    last = None
    for next in iterable:
        if last is not None:
            yield sep
            yield last
            sep = ', '
        last = next
    if sep:
        yield ', and '
    if last is not None:
        yield last

print ''.join(coma_iter(listy))
```

Comment: @SerialDownvoter: Can you please respond on posts that you downvote? This is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: This is the ugliest line of python code I've ever seen.

Comment: @wim agree, it's pretty bad. I hope this is not considered Pythonic :)

Comment: my (and @wim's) comment above applies to @Daniel's original answer which he replaced with the completely different, and novel, approach currently listed above

Answer (score 1):

It's generally bad practice to use `+` when combining strings, as it is generally slow.  Instead, you can use

```
def comma(items):
    return "{}, and {}".format(", ".join(items[:-1]), items[-1])
```

You should note, however, that this will break if you only have one item:

```
>>> comma(["spam"])
', and spam'
```

To solve that, you can either test the length of the list (`if len(items) >= 2:`), or do this, which (imho) is slightly more pythonic:

```
def comma(items):
    start, last = items[:-1], items[-1]

    if start:
        return "{}, and {}".format(", ".join(start), last)
    else:
        return last
```

As we saw above, a single item list will result in an empty value for `items[:-1]`.  `if last:` is just a pythonic way of checking if `last` is empty.

Comment: For Python 3 you can use `*start, last = items`

Answer (score 1):

Might as well round out the solutions with a recursive example.

```
>>> listy = ['item1', 'item2','item3','item4','item5', 'item6']
>>> def foo(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return ', and ' + a[0]
    return a[0] + ', ' + foo(a[1:])

>>> foo(listy)
'item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, , and item6'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `quoter` library

```
>>> import quoter
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> quoter.and_join(mylist)
'a, b, and c'
>>> quoter.or_join(mylist)
'a, b, or c'
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quoter

Comment: This is the most Javascript answer ever. 3 lines of code can accomplish this and you add a library?