# Replace last occurrence only in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following string:

```
s = 'JSON, XML, XLS, XLSX, CSV, TSV'
```

I would like to convert it to have an "and" at the end. Is it possible to do a `replace` operation only at the last occurrence of something, such as:

```
s.replace(', ', ', and ', -1)
```

==>

```
'JSON, XML, XLS, XLSX, CSV, and TSV'
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838976/grammatical-list-join-in-python) 
 and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981302/converting-a-list-into-comma-separated-string-with-and-before-the-last-item) should get you close

Comment: ' and'.join(s.rsplit(',',1))

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'JSON, XML, XLS, XLSX, CSV, TSV'

s_spl = s.split()
s_new = " ".join(s_spl[:-2]) + ' and ' + s_spl[-1]
print(s_new)
```