# List of tuples to a string with spaces and punctuations in the right places

Tags: python

A list of tuples:

```
movies = [("Chocolat", "Hulu", "Netflix", "Amazon"), ("Skyfall", "HBO Max", "Amazon"), ("Soul", "Disney+")]
```

To return: `Chocolat: Hulu, Netflix, and Amazon Skyfall: HBO Max and Amazon Soul: Disney+`

This is to be written to a file, what I have done:

```
def write_streaming_info(filename, movies):
movie_file = open(filename, "w")
for tuple_list in movies:
    tuple_list = list(tuple_list)
    movie = tuple_list.pop(0)
    tuple_list = tuple(tuple_list)

    movie_string = movie + ":" + " " +  ', '.join(tuple_list)
    movie_file.write(str(movie_string) + "\n")
return movie_string
movie_file.close()
```

The above code returns:

```
Chocolat: Hulu, Netflix, Amazon
Skyfall: HBO Max, Amazon
Soul: Disney+
```

Please help....each string to be written per line to file.

Comment: what exactly is the issue, the fact the word "and" isnt there?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981302/converting-a-list-into-comma-separated-string-with-and-before-the-last-item) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
movies = [("Chocolat", "Hulu", "Netflix", "Amazon"), ("Skyfall", "HBO Max", "Amazon"), ("Soul", "Disney+")]
def write_streaming_info(filename, movies):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for movie in movies:
            first, last = movie[0], movie[-1]
            if len(movie[1:-1]) > 0:
                movie_str = first + ': ' + ', '.join(movie[1:-1]) + ' and ' + last
            else:
                movie_str = first + ': ' + last
                
            f.write(movie_str + '\n')


write_streaming_info('movie_data.txt', movies)
```

Contents of `movie_data.txt`

```
Chocolat: Hulu, Netflix and Amazon
Skyfall: HBO Max and Amazon
Soul: Disney+
```

Comment: when the above code is returned  I get just the last line...I want to return within a loop not print...Thanks anyway

Comment: @PlumChy Return within a loop ? - Could you elaborate ?

Comment: yes...within a loop

Comment: @PlumChy If you use a ```return``` within a loop, the program stops when return is encountered the first time. I have updated my answer to write the string to a file (May be this is what you meant to say). Please check it out.

Comment: worked like magic. Does it mean then, that while writing to a file, I can't return a value?

Answer (score 1):

You should take out newline (`\n`) and add `" and "`:

```
def write_streaming_info(filename, movies):
movie_file = open(filename, "w")
for tuple_list in movies:
    tuple_list = list(tuple_list)
    movie = tuple_list[0]
    tuple_list = tuple(tuple_list[1:])

    movie_string = movie + ":" + " " +  ', '.join(tuple_list)
    movie_file.write(str(movie_tuple) + " and ")
return movie_tuple
movie_file.close()
```

Comment: If take the the new line out and add  + "and" you get and at the end of the last sentence soul: disney+ and...which is not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

*You should take out newline* (\n)  *and add* " and ":

```
def write_streaming_info(filename, movies):
movie_file = open(filename, "w")
for tuple_list in movies:
    tuple_list = list(tuple_list)
    movie = tuple_list[0]
    tuple_list = tuple(tuple_list[1:])

    movie_string = movie + ":" + " " +  ', '.join(tuple_list)
    movie_file.write(str(movie_tuple) + " and ")
return movie_tuple
movie_file.close()
```